# C# WinForms - Disable Specific Controls When Not In Use?

Tags: c#, winforms, disabled-control

Say for instance I have a C# Winforms applciations that uses a tabcontrol with four different tab pages.
Above this control on the main form are a series of groupboxes containing various buttons and textboxes relevant to the different functions running on each individual tabpage.

If I am using a particular tabpage that only makes use of some of the controls, I want to disable the others so that the user cannot accidentally click the wrong buttons.

Example Logic:

```
If(tabpage1.selected)   
{
   button3.Disabled();
}
```

Does anyone know of a way of implementing this kind of functionality?!

Regards,

EDIT:

Essentially I want to be able to disable groupboxes!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than calling `.Disabled()`, set the `.Enabled` property to `false`.  To make this easier, you can put the related controls into the same container (Panel control), and just set Enabled to false for that container.

Comment: Wow didn't realise it was literally that simple, Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

```
button3.Enabled = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
if(tabpage1.selected)   
{
   button3.Disabled();
}
```

use:

```
buttom3.Enabled = !tabpage1.selected;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button3.Enabled = false;
```